# trying to load bitmap image in python

Tags: python, pygame

I am loading an image in python what I think is proper but it still doesn't display. I don't know if the image is too big or what.

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.display.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))
mapImg = pygame.image.load("mapoftheusa.bmp")

done = False

while not done:

    window.fill((0,0,0))
    evtList = pygame.event.get()
    for evt in evtList:
         if evt.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    window.blit(mapImg, (0,0)) #<<will not blit

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: So you don't get any error output or anything - the program runs, but the image isn't displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add a call to `pygame.display.update()` right after `window.blit(mapImg, (0,0))`.

So, your complete code should be:

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.display.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))
mapImg = pygame.image.load("mapoftheusa.bmp")

done = False

while not done:

   window.fill((0,0,0))
   evtList = pygame.event.get()
   for evt in evtList:
       if evt.type == pygame.QUIT:
          done = True

   window.blit(mapImg, (0,0)) #<<will not blit
   pygame.display.update() # solution: you forgot this...

pygame.quit()
```

`pygame.display.update()` updates the window (screen) with your drawings. If you dont call it you will not see anything at all. `pygame.display.flip()` also works, but it should be used when double buffering or hardware surfaces are being used.

Also, I think it is better to initialize pygame by calling `pygame.init()` as this will initialize all of its modules including the display.